# NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.ProtocolException: The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: .net, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to do a `dotnet restore` for a .NET 3.1 project on Linux. Command fails with the following exception:

```
Terminating plugin 'CredentialProvider.Microsoft' due to an unrecoverable fault:  NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.ProtocolException: A plugin protocol exception occurred.
 ---> NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.ProtocolException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.OutboundRequestContext`1.HandleFault(Message fault)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.MessageDispatcher.OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.Connection.OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.Receiver.FireMessageReceivedEvent(Message message)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.StandardOutputReceiver.OnLineRead(Object sender, LineReadEventArgs e)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I have libssl-1.1 installed and I tried following the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#ssl-linux) to trust certificates, but does not seem to help.